# C++ operator overloading: call default function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it somehow possible to call a default function each time an overloaded operator is called?
E.g., you have a class which contains a value either in meters or yards and you want to check both of them to have equal units before applying the overloaded operator. Right now I'm using a `checkCompatibility()`-function in every overloaded operator definition, but it would be convenient if that would happen automatically for any overloaded binary operation.

Comment: Are the units represented by different classes? Like, this one is an object of `class Meter` and this one is of `class Yards`.

Comment: No, the unit information is just another member.

Comment: At least use enums for units. Or even better, simple classes with unit/value pair. Will take some work at the start, but may save a lot of work later.

Comment: I know it's not the best design, but I have to use other people's data structures a lot. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality, but [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) is designed to solve problems with unit conversion (at compile time). Your function would take a `quantity<length>` as parameter, and the library makes sure anything that is passed in is compatible and handles the conversion of units.